# Run script on multiple DBs (SQL Server)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have some update script:

```
update sometable set somecolumn = 'somevalue' where xyz = 0
```

Now let's say I have multiple databases, like DB1, DB2, DB3 and so on. How could I run this script on all of them without doing it manually?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted all databases, you can use `sp_MSforeachdb`:

> http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3441031/SQL-Server-Undocumented-Stored-Procedures-spMSforeachtable-and-spMSforeachdb.htm

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command1="UPDATE ?..sometable SET somecolumn='somevalue' WHERE xyz=0"
```

Or for specific databases, you could try some of the logic as seen here:

> http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2009/04/6-common-uses-of-undocumented-stored.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: Undocumented stored procedures are not recommended for use in anything but ad hoc scenarios because they are subject to change or even deletion at any time. You can always roll your own pretty easily though.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using cursor

- get list of all server in your lan or in network
- create cursor for that
- Than make use of sp_executesql to run you update script with forpart query

  ```
  set ANSI_NULLS ON
  set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
  GO

  CREATE PROCEDURE [sp_cross_db_query]
  @SQLQuery varchar(400)
  AS

  DECLARE @DB_Name varchar(100)
  DECLARE database_cursor CURSOR FOR 

  SELECT DatabaseName 
  FROM Management.dbo.Customers

  OPEN database_cursor

  FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name

  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
  BEGIN 
      exec(
          'USE [' + @DB_Name + '];' +
          @SQLQuery
          )
         FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name 
  END
  CLOSE database_cursor 
  DEALLOCATE database_cursor
  ```

  to run the query

  ```
    exec sp_cross_db_query 'SELECT count(*) FROM Products'
  ```

Comment: Thanks, can u give me some SQL please?

Comment: Thanks,
    FROM Management.dbo.Customers is causing some trouble...whats wrong?

Comment: The answer assumes you have a table that contains a list of databases, I think

Comment: SELECT [name] FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases did the trick, thanks!